# Neo4j ShortestPath duplicate properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm currently using the built-in shortest path algorithm from Neo4j.

```
MATCH p = shortestpath((s:Node {Name: "A"})-[Link*1..500]->(e:Node {Name: "B"})) 
WHERE ALL(x in relationships(p) WHERE x.Value = true)
RETURN p
```

The problem is that when I run the algorithm, it can return the 2nd "B" despite passing the first "B" (orange line). How would I make it just return the first instance of "B"?

I know I could simply solve the issue by using the unique Id's but I need to use the names.

[image]

```
public class Node
{
   public long Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public long X {get;set;}
   public long Y {get;set;}
}

public class Link {
   public bool Value {get;set;}
   public long Length {get;set;}
}
```

Thanks in advance and feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what the result  you have with the query, and what the result you want. Can you describe it more precisely ?

Comment: The current query returns the orange line but I want it to return when it hits the first node called B. I'll update the image once I'm at home to include what I'd like.

Comment: So it should only touch a node named "B" as the last node of the path?

Comment: It shouldn&#39;t return that last B as it has already passed a node called B. It should return (a)-()-()-()-(b) not (a)-()-()-()-(b)-(b)

Comment: @Liam The query you have now is working as it's suppose to, so in order to exclude the second "B" node, you need to update the filter logic as to why that path is not also valid. So the correct answer depends on what the exact restriction you need to add is. It sounds like you want no intermediate nodes to also have the name "B". I don't know what the story of the blank nodes is in the picture above, so I don't know if that is actually true. If I am understanding correctly, you need to add `AND (x = e OR x.name <> "B")` to your filter so that only the last node is named "B"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your query, neo4j is going to find every `A` node and every `B` node and then find all of the shortest paths from each `A` to each `B`. What is rendered in the console UI is all of the resulting nodes from that query with every relationship that connects each of them. If you click on the *_Text_* button on the left side of the query window it will become clearer what is happening. You will see a discreet row for every shortest path matched between A dn B nodes.

After reading your question, I expect what you are after is a query that matches a specific `A` node and then traverses until it encounters a `B` node.

The apoc path expansion procedure call may be better suited to your needs. If you could add a label `B` to the B node(s) then you could use the `apoc.path.expand` to find the path you are seeking.

You can use the following to set the `B` label.

```
MATCH (n:Node {Name: 'B'}
SET n:B
```

Here is a sample query using `apoc.path.expand` that should stop at the first `B` node encountered.

```
MATCH (a:Node {Name: 'A'})
WITH a
CALL apoc.path.expand(a, 'Link', '+Node|/B', 1, 500) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

Comment: The first part of you answer provided me with a solution to use the reduce function. I added:


WITH p, reduce(s = 0, r IN relationships(p) | s + r.Length) AS dist
RETURN p AS shortestPath 
ORDER BY dist ASC
LIMIT 1